# Как переместить несколько разных файлов в одну папку командой move в консоли

Tags: windows, cmd, консоль

Надо переместить файлы `111.txt, 222.java` в папку `12345`. Папка и файлы находятся в одной директории.

Пишу команду `move 111.txt, 222.java 12345\`. Получаю `"Ошибка в синтаксисе команды."`

В хелпе написано следующее:

```
>help move
Перемещение файлов и переименование файлов и папок

Перемещение одного или более файлов:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [диск:][путь]имя_файла1[,...] назначение

Переименование папки:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [диск:][путь]имя_папки новое_имя_папки

  [диск:][путь]имя_файла1 Определяет местоположение файла или файлов, которые
                          необходимо переместить.
  Назначение              Определяет новое местоположение файла. Назначение
                          может состоять из буквы диска (с последующим
                          двоеточием), имени папки или их комбинации. При
                          перемещении только одного файла, можно указать и его
                          новое имя, если хотите выполнить его одновременное
                          переименование при перемещении.
  [диск:][путь]имя_папки  Определяет папку, которую необходимо переименовать.
  новое_имя_папки         Определяет новое имя папки.

  /Y                      Перезаписывать существующие файлы назначения без
                          предупреждения.
  /-Y                     Предупреждать при перезаписи существующего файла
                          назначения.

Ключ /Y может присутствовать в значении переменной среды окружения COPYCMD.
Оно может перекрываться ключом /-Y в командной строке. По умолчанию
используется предупреждение о перезаписи, если только команда MOVE не
выполняется как часть пакетного файла.
```

Comment: По маске *.* отрабатывает. Не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во встроенном хелпе ошибка. Команда `move` не умеет копировать несколько файлов. Правильная документация находится по следующим адресам:

- https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true
- https://jpsoft.com./help/move.htm

([Источник](https://superuser.com/questions/371302/cmd-move-move-a-couple-of-files))

Answer (score 0):

Умеет если маска "*.Расширение", а вот с "*.*" - проблема

Comment: А почему ответ общий? Случайно?